# c++ inheritance simple error

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Vehicle
{
    private:
    string model;
    int price;

    public:
        Vehicle()
    {
        model="";
        price=0;
    }

    Vehicle(string model, int price);

    void setModel(string mee)
    {
        model=mee;
    }

    string getModel()
    {
        return model;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Vehicle veh;
    cout<<"enter model:"<<endl;
    cin>>veh.setModel(string mee); //expected primary-expression before mee    
}
```

Whats wrong with it? im kind of newbie on c++. and i didnt get it.. Please help me about int main.

Comment: There is no inheritance in here, and I can't even figure out what you want `cin>>veh.setModel(string mee);` to do.

Comment: http://homes.ieu.edu.tr/ikorkmaz/courses/SE116_Spring2013-2014/sampleInheritanceApplication.pdf

Im trying to solve this question.

Answer (score 3):

When you wrote this:

```
cin>>veh.setModel(string mee); //expected primary-expression before mee
```

**I think** you wanted to write this.

```
string mee;           // Create a string
cin >> mee;           // Read user input into the string
veh.setModel( mee );  // Pass that string to Vehicle::setModel()
```

Comment: int main()
{
    Vehicle veh;
    veh.setModel(string mee)=coupe;
}

In that case, would be right something like that?